# How to get a list of libxml2 API?

Tags: xml, libxml2

I am actually quite new to xml and libxml2.

I can not find a list of API in the libxml2 website, all I can find is lots of links that makes no sense for me.

Can anyone provide any link for the API list or some document to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "libxml2 api" returned

http://xmlsoft.org/html/

which is the full api reference.  "parser" and "tree" are the most important parts for using the tree-based API, but there are plenty of examples available at "Code Examples" on the left.

http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html

Comment: "parser" and "tree" are the most important parts for using the tree-based API".
This is exactly the thing I am finding.  thanks.